# Improve speed of UpdateOne in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection in mongodb with 1 million documents. Every few hours, I need to update the collection with a few hundred new documents. Each document has a corresponding unique 'house-id_listing' which I use as the unique "id". If the 'house-id_listing' exists in the collection, I want to replace it with the new document, otherwise, I simply insert the new document which does not currently exist in the collection. I am using the following pymongo code to do this:

```
bulk_ops = []
for listing_id, new_value in data.items():
    bulk_ops.append(
        pymongo.UpdateOne(
            {'house-id_listing': listing_id},
            {"$set": new_value}
            ,upsert=True
        )
    )
result = db['detached'].bulk_write(bulk_ops)
print(result.bulk_api_result)
```

However, it is extremely slow. It takes almost an hour to update 300 documents, which is way too slow. How can I improve the speed of this?

Comment: Do you have an index on `house-id_listing`?

Comment: I just did and speed is way faster. I think that is the solution.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What sort of index should I create? I basically guessed in Compass and it seemed to work. I did an ascending text index.

Comment: As simple plain default index.